# How to make a table of contents for a report?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Table of Contents]

I need to implement the table of contents given in the image. My question is in the how do I generate those sections in the table of content. And also how to write the number in Roman?

Comment: If you used `\section`, `\chapter`, etc. in creating the document, the command `\tableofcontents` should be sufficient to generate a table of contents.  To tailor its appearance, there are packages like `tocloft` and `titlesec` that you can examine.  What have you tried?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: I used 
\chapter {chapter name}
\section {section name}
but the generated output is not same as given output.

Comment: As, I said, if you managed to generate a `\tableofcontents` that contains the right information, but in the wrong format, the packages I mentioned are helpful at customizing the appearance.  If your invocation of `\tableofcontents` does not generate the proper basic information, you would have to post a small compiling example to demonstrate it.  In any event, it is proper for you to edit your question to post a small  working or nonworking example that shows the issue.

Comment: where should I include \tocloft and \titlesec ?

Comment: As packages, they are invoked in the preamble with `\usepackage{titlesec}` or `\usepackage{tocloft}`.  That, however, just makes the multiplicity of commands of those packages available, which you then have to invoke, as needed, to change the TableOfContents (toc) appearance.  See http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft and/or http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec to read the documentation for these packages.

Comment: It would be helpful to you to search this site for `tocloft` and/or `titlesec` to see other questions about how to use these packages.

Comment: Thank you, for your time. Could you help me with one more thing? In the given image, on the left-hand side of chapter name, it is roman number. How do I generate those numbers?

Comment: If the argument is a LaTeX "counter", then `\Roman{chapter}` would accomplish it for "chapter"s.  If not, then `\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\thesection\relax}` where in this example, `\thesection` is a string containing a numeric value.

Comment: If you load `titlesec` it will be simpler to use `titletoc` (same bundle).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes what should I write? \Roman{chapter} {Introduction}?

Comment: You really need to read the package documentation.  You would still use `\chapter{Introduction}`, but add in the preamble, `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}`

Comment: So \Roman is in the \tolcoft or \titlesec packages?

Comment: No, `\Roman` is basic LaTeX. And so is `\thechapter`, which denotes the textual representation of the integer counter `chapter`.

Comment: \renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}  worked well, thank you. But it also generates roman number for \section where the section will contain English number i.e. 1,2,3..

Comment: @sphoenix: `\thechapter` is contained in the definition of `\thesection` (of course), to provide a consistent numbering scheme. It's not recommended to have Chapter II (Roman numbers) and a section of that chapter numbered with arabic figures again, say `2.5`.

Comment: I am very confused. [The very same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364795/table-of-contents-doubts) with a completely different way of commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.05em]{\bigskip}%
{\contentslabel[\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel}]{1em}\enspace\textsc}%numbered\contentslabel
{\hspace*{-1em}\textsc}%numberless
{\hfill\contentspage}%
%
\titlecontents{section}[1.6em]{\smallskip}%
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%numbered
{}%numberless
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}%

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{A first chapter}
\section{A first section}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[5-6]

\chapter{A second chapter}
\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]