# Customizing the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis, report

[image: I need the chapter numbers as in center not left and page no. also blue or everything is need black color, is it possible?]

I need the chapter numbers as in center not left and page no. also blue or everything is need black color, is it possible?

Comment: The screenshot you've posted leaves a lot of criteria in doubt. E.g., there's a column header named "Page No.", yet the sample entries themselves don't appear to be associated with page numbers.

Comment: this is the sample page only,  I need page no. also

Comment: Queries of the "do this for me" variety are frowned upon at this site. You really need to state what you've tried so far. Looking at the screenshot you've posted, I must confess that it's not even clear what the connection to LaTeX and friends may be. Do edit your posting to indicate what, if anything, you've tried. Do tell us which document class you use, what the page and text block sizes are, which fonts and font sizes are to be used, and (last but not least) if it's true that **EVERYTHING HAS TO BE TYPESET IN BOLD AND ALL-UPPERCASE.**

Comment: Now you check I change the screenshot what i needed.  this is for my synopsis format, Times new roman, font 14, bold, caps

Comment: It is article class file only...

Comment: We would like you to edit your question to include code for a minimal but complete document showing what you've got and what you've tried. Presumably you have some code e.g. loading the fonts. Create some sample `\section{}`s and create the table of contents so people have something to format. Right now, this is just a do-it-all-for-me. 'Send me the code' - that's not how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: The fact that you use the `article` document class is significant: Since it doesn't feature a command called `\chapter`, it is *impossible* to generate a table of contents that shows chapter-level headers.

Comment: Dear Mico it is possible in book class file

Comment: I am very confused. [The very same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364756/how-to-make-a-table-of-contents-for-a-report) with a completely different way of commenting.

Comment: you are correct @Johannes_B but my problem is the title of content is middle

Comment: It seems so. The person who did this exampe page included also the obvious strings `page number`, `title`  and `page number`. The example page was probably created using a word processor and internally using a table. Result: Something unreadable. And then they addded ALL-UPPERCASE and **BOLD** to make it even worse.

Comment: I suggest to read an [Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) (<- Lin to free ebook). This will get you familiar with the most basic stuff. You can also  have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with the format of this helping site.

Comment: Changing the question time after time is not how this community works.

Comment: Where can we get the complete specifications?

Comment: I need the the chapter no. 1, 2, 3... becomes middle its left in the page, i need the chap. no. in middle

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is a language barrier at the moment.  Try google translate, it does a decent job.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B I need the chapter nos. 1,2,3... in middle of the first row but it is in left in the first row

Answer (score 4):

All i take from the image: A centered title, chapter numbers (if any) on the left, then the titles, and the page numbers on the right.

[image: kamalToc]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[indentunnumbered]{unnumberedtotoc}%https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Section_numbering
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Wombat}
\addchap{Capybara}
\chapter{An insanely long chapter title that nobody will ever
read entirely Duck}
\end{document}
```

Comment: etoolbox is not working

Comment: `etoolbox` is not the issue. You'll need the `unnumberedtotoc.sty` file from https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

Comment: yes I downloaded and now its work thank you @Troy.  I have one more doubt if i need to remove the chapter no. for the particular chapter, how i can remove the chapter no. for any chapters

Comment: You mean like `capybara` in the answer above? Use `\addchap` that's defined by `unnumberedtotoc.sty` instead of `\chapter`

Comment: Dear @Troy please see my image on top,  In abstract there is not chapter no. I need like that...

Comment: What's wrong with `\addchap{Abstract}`?

Comment: okay its working thank you @Troy I need to change the font size of contents